# Win8 wp8 binding variation?

Tags: c#, binding, windows-8, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I pass an application from wp8 to win8 and all binding failed in textblock and i don't understand why.
Exemple textblock :

```
<TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding SimulClassement,Converter={StaticResource ClassementConverter}}" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityResultat}" Foreground="#FFFF7901" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

My property is like :

```
private string _simulClassement;
        public string SimulClassement
        {
            get { return _simulClassement; }
            set
            {
                _simulClassement = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SimulClassement");
            }
        }
```

SimulClassement property is already set in my viewmodel but i have nothing in view...
I forgot something???

Regars.

Edit:

```
public class ClassementConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                return " Classement : " + value;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I set this property with : `SimulClassement = GetSimulClassement(CalculPoints(CalculNombreVictoire(CalculVe2I(SelectedProfile.Classement), SelectedProfile.Classement)), SelectedProfile.Classement, false);`

Comment: Did you check the console to see of there is any error?

Comment: No error and my model / view model is exactly the same.

Comment: you could try to put a breakpoint in ClassementConverter

Comment: another you can try to check is trying to set the text to something static to see if it is actually a binding pb or the TextBlock is just not showing up

Comment: not pass in my ClassementConverter when i launch but i tested in my wp8 application and it's same.If i set with basic text like text="toto" it's worked.

Comment: I don't see hhow the wp8 version could be working if it is not passing by the converter, are you sure you put the breakpoint at the right place?

Comment: two other thing you could try is Text="{Binding SimulClassement}" and Text="{Binding ,Converter={StaticResource ClassementConverter}}" to check if it is a problem with the property or the converter

Comment: also you could check that both the converter and the property are not in a private class

Comment: i pass in converter when i go to the view, not when i do an action...but this worked in wp8...it's really weird!!

Comment: could you put the code where you "pass in converter when i go to the view", I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: i add my converter in my post...always converter are call when property is modified?

Comment: #BenoitCatherinet i pass in my breackpoint only when i go to my view.When i see view / ui. Not when my property changed.

Comment: always converter are call when property is modified => yes normally it should

Comment: ok so it break when the view is loaded on both windows 8 and wp8 but not after that?

Comment: yes but wp8 binding work.

Comment: So probably on wp8 the value is already the right one on load while on windows 8 the value is not yet the right one? When you are inside your converter you could check what value is the value

Comment: when i write text="{Binding converter=XXXX}" i see my view model so it's worked but when i write my property, i see nothing. And value is null when i come in view

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint inside the setter of SimulClassement to check that the property is really changed somewhere

Comment: I have an toher binding who work because i use a messenger for pass value and when i come to view, it is not null but...hummm when i add breakpoint i set but after i don't get for my binding...it's really (bad word)....I have never got a problem cause binding in wp8...

Answer (score 0):

i found my probleme. I have copy past my code with a wrong thing.When i copy past my code, propertychange event was not know in my all view model.So, like a noob, i create for all classes the property and method. My viewmodel was hanging to my property change who was null all time...I need juste to create one time.(virtual method)